# How do I host an .apk file online

Tags: cloud, apk

I am putting an android test version file in the cloud. My dev is linking the demo to a file that he wants stored online like a photo- but I don't really know what that means.

I have the apk file locally but don't know what I can use to just store it in the cloud so he can access it. Can't use google docs bc .apk is not supported, should I use something like dropbox?

Comment: Actually- I might be able to answer my own question and use gdocs after all and not "convert it"- then set the privacy to anyone with the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put the *.apk wherever you like (although, obviously, it should be someplace that other people can't modify it). An enumeration of the different ways to do that is probably outside the scope of a StackOverflow answer, but Dropbox would be sufficient for this, as you suggested.

One thing to note is that anyone downloading the *.apk will need to be able to accept applications from non-Market sources. This is a setting they can edit in `Settings > Applications`.